# How to implement a simple container with placement new and emplace functionality?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, placement-new, emplace

I need to implement a container to hold an amount of elements and for some reason, it has to work without any heap allocation. Another requirement is, that the container elements should not be copied or moved in any way. They have to constructed directly into the memory allocated by the container.

For that, I decided to use placement new and delegate the memory management completely to the container implementation (found some useful information about placement new at [drdobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/calling-constructors-with-placement-new/232901023)).

A running example is found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/defd059e8250c685).
(Please note, that the use of `new uint8_t[size]` and `std::queue` is just to keep the example simple. My real code has more complex, heap-less implementation instead.)

This perfectly works so far, as the client code has to put elements into the container with calls like:

```
executer.push(new (executer) MyRunnable("Hello", 123));
```

Now I want do remove the need of the repeated write `executer` in this statement. I would rather like to write something like e.g.:

```
executer.pushNew(MyRunnable("Hello", 123));
```

or

```
executer.pushNew(MyRunnable, "Hello", 123);
```

maybe by providing an appropriate template but I failed to write one (no preprocessor macros, please).

I'd found some useful information about `std::allocator` here at [drdobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-what-are-allocato/184403759) but don't know how to apply it to my problem (further, the article is of anno 2000 and so don't take use of possible C++11 advantages).

Could one help me to find a way to not longer need to give the `executer` twice?

**Edit:** After successful approving [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926314/2069064)'s answer, I'd updated my running example code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc2c00c71f545df5).

And for the history, here the original example code of my initial question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>


class Runnable {
    // Runnable should be uncopyable and also unmovable
    Runnable(const Runnable&) = delete;
    Runnable& operator = (const Runnable&) = delete;    
    Runnable(const Runnable&&) = delete;
    Runnable& operator = (const Runnable&&) = delete;    
public:
    explicit Runnable() {}
    virtual ~Runnable() {}
    virtual void run() = 0;
};


class MyRunnable: public Runnable {
public:
    explicit MyRunnable(const char* name, int num): name(name), num(num) {}
    virtual void run() override {
        std::cout << name << " " << num << std::endl;
    }
private:
    const char* name;
    int num;
};


class Executer {
    // Executer should be uncopyable and also unmovable
    Executer(const Executer&) = delete;
    Executer& operator = (const Executer&) = delete;    
    Executer(const Executer&&) = delete;
    Executer& operator = (const Executer&&) = delete;    
public:
    explicit Executer() {    
    }

    void* allocateEntry(size_t size) {
        // this heap allocation is just to keep this example simple
        // my real implementation uses it's own memory management instead (blockpool)
        return new uint8_t[size];
    }

    void push(Runnable* entry) {
        queue.push(entry);
    }

    template <typename R> // this don't works
    void pushNew(R) {
        push(new (*this) R);
    }

    inline friend void* operator new(size_t n, Executer& executer) {
        return executer.allocateEntry(n);
    }

    void execute() {
        while (queue.size() > 0) {
            Runnable* entry = queue.front();
            queue.pop();
            entry->run();
            // Now doing "placement delete"
            entry->~Runnable();
            uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(entry);
            delete[] p;
        }

    }

private:
    // this use of std::queue is just to keep this example simple
    // my real implementation uses it's own heap-less queue instead
    std::queue<Runnable*> queue {};
};


int main() {
    Executer executer;
    executer.push(new (executer) MyRunnable("First", 1));
    executer.push(new (executer) MyRunnable("Second", 2));
    executer.push(new (executer) MyRunnable("Third", 3));

    // but want to use it more like one this 
    //executer.pushNew(MyRunnable("Fifth", 5));  // how to implement it?
    //executer.pushNew(MyRunnable, "Sixth", 6);  // or maybe for this usage?

    executer.execute();
}
```

Comment: Are the number of elements known at compile time?  Could you use `std::array`?

Comment: No, `std::array` cannot be used. Further, the way how the container manages the memory has to be completely private.

Comment: Have you looked at std::vectors implementation of emplace back? Sounds like this is exactly what you need (ignoring the haep vs stack issue, which is a sepatate concerne)

Comment: Come to think of it, you could probably even build a wrapper around std::vector with a stack allocator

Comment: Instead of passing a `MyRunnable` to `push()`, could you pass the arguments (`name` and `num`) instead?  Then you could have the `new` inside the `push()`.

Comment: I think I have done the same thing before (in AddNew function): https://bitbucket.org/darkgazeorg/gorgon-game-engine/src/a1c8c5fbcd51b734c6ab6234e0287e05515dc5d9/Source/Gorgon/Containers/Collection.h?at=4.x-dev&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: The `MyRunnable` ctor arguments are not known by the container and there might be a `FooRunnable` and a `BarRunnable` with even different parameters. Sounds a bit like have to use variadic template …

Comment: this question is possibly a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628484/custom-container-emplace-with-variadic-templates

you are asking for "emplace" functionality wich is inserted by design (at least in C++11, I start to forget about old C++ xD)

Comment: You're right, my question is exactly about »emplace« functionality (and now, I'll rename the member function in my code. For this, it might duplicate. But I think that the answers of Jarod42 and Barry are really beautiful and clear. Finally I'd added »emplace« to the questions subject.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With:

```
template <typename R, typename... Ts>
void pushNew(Ts&&... args) {
    push(new (*this) R(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
}
```

You can write:

```
executor.PushNew<MyRunnable>("Hello", 123);
```

instead of

```
executer.push(new (executer) MyRunnable("Hello", 123));
```

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, the answer from Barry is much better.

Answer (score 27):

There are two things wrong with this:

```
template <typename R> // this don't works
void pushNew(R) {
    push(new (*this) R);
}
```

The first is answered by [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926314/2069064) in that you want to do:

```
template <typename R, typename... Ts>
void pushNew(Ts&&... args) {
    push(new (*this) R(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
}
```

but even more importantly... `new (*this) R` is *really bizarre*. It looks like you're constructing an `R` over yourself! But you're not, you're just using that syntax to call your allocator. That horribly violates the principle of least surprise. It took me quite a while to understand what was going on.

What you should to is just use your allocator directly:

```
template <typename R, typename... Ts>
void pushNew(Ts&&... args) {
    void* slot = allocateEntry(sizeof(R));
    push(new (slot) R(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
}
```

That is a lot easier to understand.

Comment: should be accepted. Random navigators be aware this is the answer I prefer! :)